# Consume a WordPress site data from another WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

I am facing an issue with wordpress. I have two sites. On the first site there is a form that takes inputs and **stores values** in custom fields to be later used for various calculations on that site.

On the other website, I need to access these same values from the first website and use them thoughout the second website in multiple elements. So I've come up with an idea that because those stored values on the first website are already being displayed (as in, they are in some HTML elements in a visible page), I could just get that first website content and than do one of two things:

1. Create similar custom fields in the second website, and write a function in functions.php that would take the values from the first website and update custom fields in the second website every time it loads, so then I could use those values throughout the second website (it seems to me that this is a stupid solution).
2. Write a function in functions.php (in the second website, the one that needs to receive the values from the first) that would create javascript variables from that first website, so that could be used to populate all the elements I need.

Maybe there is some much better solution for all of this. To be fair, this is the first time I am doing something like this, so you could say I am very unexperienced.

Is there another better solution for this? And if there isn't, which of the two solutions listed above is a better one?

Comment: How about pulling the data from the first sites db (as they are stored) and display them on the seconds site?
Alternative solution would be to create a JSON response that the second page can retrieve.
Both solutions require that you have access both sites db/code base

Comment: That sounds good, so let me clarify: there is a way for a custom fields  data to be pulled from one site's db to another website? If there is, could you tell me where to start, because I have never worked with wp db and I have never fetched data from one site to another. (But I know basic sql and how databases work)

Comment: If I was in your position. I would create a view on the first site, that basically serves a JSON response of the data you need on the second site.  (on the second site): You could use `file_get_contents('http://first.site/url/to/json/view')` or just fetch the data with the client aka the browser, using `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though there are many possible options and that may generate debates based on individuals' experiences and or prevailing conditions, you can easily achieve your intended goal by consuming data from your *site one* into your *site two*, then, apply whatever necessary logic and actions needed there (in your *site two*).

Using the latest version of [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/), you can take leverage on the in-built [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) in order to access the desired data from *site one* within *site two*.